# What is the correct VERB for this action?

Tags: meaning

In American movies, I often see the police use a tool (which looks like a stick and is powered by electricity, I think) to move from head to toe of a person to check if there is something on their body. So can anybody tell me what the verb is to describe that action, please? Thanks.

Is it "electric-screen", I wonder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the police do it as well, but at the airports, security will sometimes screen you with one of those hand-held instruments, and it's called a "wand". The verb is also "to wand". Examples: "They wanded him at the airport."; "Why did you get wanded, and I didn't?"

See this [Daily Mail article](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3522240/Four-year-old-girl-wanded-MCG-babies-scanned-going-AFL-games.html) for pictures of it.

[image: A four-year-old girl called Holly was photographed by her mum Bec being scanned by security at the gates of the MCG on Saturday after they went to watch the game between Essendon and Melbourne Demons]

Caption: *A four-year-old girl called Holly was photographed by her mum Bec being scanned by security at the gates of the MCG on Saturday after they went to watch the game between Essendon and Melbourne Demons*